# Ignore some things with n_distinct() in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

Suppose I have this data set:

```
test <- data.frame(thing = c(rep(1, 4), 
                         rep(2, 4), 
                         rep(3, 4), 
                         rep(4, 3), 
                         rep(5, 1)), 
                   thing2 = c(c("a", "b", "c", "c"), 
                              c("a", "b", "c", "d"),
                              c("a", "b", "b", "b"),
                              c("a", "b", "c"), 
                              c("d")))
```

and I want to know how many individual `thing2` are associated with each `thing` so,

```
test %>%
  group_by(thing) %>%
  summarize(nDistinct = n_distinct(thing2))
```

gives me

```
  thing nDistinct
1     1         3
2     2         4
3     3         2
4     4         3
5     5         1
```

which is fine.  But, what I'm *really* interested in is the number of distinct things that *aren't* `d` in each factor level.

I could rewrite the statement above and include a `filter()` so that

```
test %>%
  group_by(thing) %>%
  filter(thing2 != "d") %>%
  summarize(nDistinct = n_distinct(thing2))
```

gives me

```
  thing nDistinct
1     1         3
2     2         3
3     3         2
4     4         3
```

but I lose the fact that when `thing == 5`, it gets dropped from the resulting data frame.

What I'd like to see is a `dplyr` (or something else) statement that gives me

```
  thing nDistinct
1     1         3
2     2         3
3     3         2
4     4         3
5     5         0
```

Is that possible?

I have the sneaking suspicion that I'm overlooking something very simple here.

Comment: You can always use the "traditional" `length(unique(thing[thing2 != "d"]))`

Comment: I knew it was something simple that I was overlooking!  Between this and the answer below, I'm banging my head on my desk wondering why I didn't see it already!

Comment: a good tactics to remember it ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would go for:

```
test %>%
  group_by(thing) %>%
  summarize(nDistinct = n_distinct(thing2) - any(thing2=="d"))

Source: local data frame [5 x 2]

thing nDistinct
(dbl)     (int)
1     1         3
2     2         3
3     3         2
4     4         3
5     5         0
```

So that even if you have one or more `d`, `any` returns 1 and remove it from the `distinct`.

Comment: I knew I was missing something simple.  Thanks for pointing this out!

Comment: A more dplyrish/idiomatic way might be `test %>% distinct %>% group_by(thing) %>% tally(thing2 != "d")`